# Socket.io connection from remote

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, socket.io, jxcore

I'm doing a real time application with jxcore (nodejs for Plesk Panel) and I'm new on nodejs.
Application file index.js is running on domain mydomain.it:

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );

var io = socket.listen( server );

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
  client.on( 'message', function( data ) {
    io.sockets.emit( 'message', {
      name:data.name,
      surname:data.surname
    });
  });
});
server.listen( 8080 );
```

On the same domain there is a client page, for example mydomain.it/app, that includes:

```
<script src="../node/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../node/js/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="../node/js/nodeClient.js"></script>
```

This is my nodeClient.js file:

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://mydomain.it:8080' ); 
socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
  var obj = {
    name:data.name,
    surname:data.surname
  }
  // do something
});
```

Now, I need to connect to the websocket from an Android app, installed on several devices.
So there is a domain that contain a nodejs server and a client. And other remote android devices (with an html5 app, developed with jquery mobile).
But I can't connect to the socket, it returns errors (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on chrome browser).

From the client page on the domain I can connect to the socket only if I change

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://mydomain.it:8080' );
```

to

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' );
```

But of course I can't connect to the server from remote devices using localhost. Socket.io is installed only on mydomain.it

Is it possible to realize this kind of application?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that port 8080 is open to the Internet on the server behind the domain ? And not just from itself, i.e. from 127.0.0.1. Can you access the client page itself ?

Comment: No, from mydomain.it:8080 I can't access. But 127.0.0.1:8080 is reached from a page inside domain. Mybe I just have to open port 8080?

Comment: If you can't even reach the client page itself and load the html, you should for sure check you firewall settings

Comment: @pat It is not clear to me how are you running server and client? Server from JXcore extension for Plesk (Domains tab) ? An your node client from your client machine?